# I am not able to fetch the courses according to the category

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material, ngfor, angular9

I am trying to run this *ngFor="courses of getCoursesByCategory(categories.key)" to fetch the courses according to the category parameter. I am not getting any error but the courses are not being displayed. I have a database which looks like this [Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLm94.png). What should I do?

courses.component.html:-

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let categories of categories" [label]="categories.label">
        <div class="cardList">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let courses of getCoursesByCategory(categories.key)">
                <mat-card class="cardListItem">
                    <mat-card-header>
                        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
                        <mat-card-title>{{ courses.title }}</mat-card-title>
                    </mat-card-header>
                    <img mat-card-image [src]="courses.urlImage">
                    <mat-card-content>
                        <p>{{ courses.description }}</p>
                    </mat-card-content>
                    <mat-card-actions>
                        <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Add Course</button>
                    </mat-card-actions>
                </mat-card>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

courses.component.ts:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/modules/common/services/category.service';
import { CourseService } from '../../services/course.service';
import { mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css']
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  categories: any[];
  courses: any[];
  sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private categoryService : CategoryService, private courseService : CourseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.categoryService.getAllcategories()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(categories => this.courseService.getAllCourses().pipe(
        map(courses => [categories, courses])
      ))).subscribe(([categories, courses]) => {
        this.categories = categories;
        this.courses = courses;
      });
  }

  getCoursesByCategory(key)
  {
      return this.courses.filter(course => course.category==key);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() : void
  {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the reference name as both are same(categories)

```
 <mat-tab *ngFor="let category of categories" [label]="category.label">
```

replace all the categories to category in other elements.

Instead of `<ng-container *ngFor="let courses of getCoursesByCategory(categories.key)">`

use `<ng-container *ngFor="let courses of category ">`

now courses will contain element of category.

also if you can provide the json, i can help you better if this approach doesn't help

Comment: I'm sorry sir but this doesn't help

Comment: can you provide json?

Comment: the problem is that the logic of getCoursesByCategory(key) function is not working, and the html part inside ng-container is not working. if you can help correcting it please.

Comment: @user13321892  i can help if i check the json or you can create a stackblitz and share the link.

Comment: this stackblitz doesn't have the code you are working on. It's an empty project.  Do you have the api response which you can share?